# What is the difference between .toString("F") and .toString("G") in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, tostring

According to .NET [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-decimal-tostring(system-string)):

```
decimal value = 16325.62m;
string specifier;

// Use standard numeric format specifiers.
specifier = "G";
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", specifier, value.ToString(specifier));
// Displays:    G: 16325.62


specifier = "F";
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", specifier, value.ToString(specifier));
// Displays:    F: 16325.62
```

What is the difference between `"F"` and `"G"`? Are there any circumstances in which these would produce different results?

Comment: See the link in your link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings  - F = fixed, G = "Result: The more compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation." ( = E)

Comment: You don't need to ask us when you can simply read the relevant documentation. All you needed to do was click on `ToString` and press F1 to go to that documentation and it would provide a link to the documentation for the valid format specifiers. Microsoft have sunk thousands of man-hours into that documentation. Use it.

Comment: Hey, if you are going to say "according to the docs...", at least point to the right one (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings). Even better, extract quotes from that page (the correct one) so we can read the two definitions. I really didn't appreciate having to follow a link to understand your question. Having to follow two links borders on insulting

Comment: To see the difference try these numbers: `73m`, `3.1415926m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"F" (Fixed-Point Format)`: This specifier formats a numeric value using fixed-point notation. When you use `"F"` with ToString() on a decimal value like 16325.62m, it retains the specified number of decimal places. For instance, if you use `"F2"`, it will display two decimal places, like 16325.62.

`"G" (General Format)`: This specifier automatically chooses the format based on the value. For decimal numbers, `"G"` retains as many significant digits as required to uniquely identify the number, and it does not add trailing zeros after the decimal point.

In your example, when you use `"F"` or `"G"` with `ToString()` on the decimal value 16325.62m, both produce the same result because the number of significant digits is such that they both display the same output: 16325.62.